# How to get only a date from a datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I have a report to do, so I need to return a date from a `datetime` column, but it need to come only with the date from the column.

I am using the Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I've already tried to use `CONVERT(name_of_the_column, GETDATE())` but I realised the it only works to return the current datetime from the server.

How can I do that?

Comment: That's not convert's syntax. The first parameter should be a datatype name, such as `DATE`, not a column name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I get it. I've tried the both ways, but nothing has worked

Comment: @LeandroTorres - In comments to two different answers (which, to me, look like they answer your question), you've said "keeps turning back time". What does that mean? I think it would be useful to have a concrete input and expected output in your question statement like `declare @t datetime = '2022-10-21 09:13'; /* I'd like a way to convert @t into «expectation here» */`

Comment: I strongly recommend you create an example demonstrating your problem. For example, this demo shows it work perfectly fine; https://dbfiddle.uk/6VR03hZI  The reasons for creating an example are given here [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) and here [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to return a date from a datetime column

There are several things to cover in order to fully answer this.

First, if that really is a `datetime` column, something to understand here is `datetime` values will **ALWAYS** have a time component. It's even right there in the name. There is no way to return a `datetime` value that does not have a time portion. The closest you can get is casting to a string or `date`, but *that's not really the same thing.* Typically what happens instead is the time portion is truncated back to midnight (all 0s)... but that time portion is *still there*. That's where you see answers like this:

```
dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, name_of_the_column), 0)
```

or this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), name_of_the_column,101)
```

The next to thing to understand is the one thing you **should not do** is convert the date value to a string, as in the second example.

Because of cultural/internationalization issues, converting datetime or numeric values to and from strings is much slower and more error-prone than you'd like to believe. It's something to avoid, and probably best left to your client code or reporting tool.

A final consideration is `datetime` values **NEVER** have any time zone awareness (that would involve `datetime2`). So if there's anything on the client to show this in a local time it may be picking the wrong offset. Do that with a value where the time portion was already truncated, and you can end up with unexpected results.

Put all this together, and what you should do is `CAST()` to a `DATE`:

```
CAST(name_of_the_column AS DATE)
```

Now I have seen this comment on another answer with this recommendation:

> keeps turning back time

This could be the time zone mismatch I've already mentioned, or it could also be that `name_of_the_column` is **not really a datetime column** in the first place, but rather a string/varchar column *pretending* to be a datetime column. In that case, the `CAST()` may be parsing the values with different cultural rules than you expect. It goes back to that whole "slower and more error-prone/something to avoid" thing again. Also in this is the case the schema is considered **broken**, and you really should fix it to use *actual* `datetime` or `datetime2` values.

---

Speaking of "fix it", I also noticed the SQL Server 2014 tag. SQL Server 2014 has been fully end of life since 2019. That means it has not received any updates — **not even critical security patches!** — for several years now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. Updating to a supported version is job #1 here.

Comment: I finded a way to solve this question as you have mentioned using the report tool of the system used in the company I work for. About the SQL Server 2014, there nothing I can do, because the enterprise owner of the system provides this DB

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONVERT(DATE, <expression>)`.

```
create table t (dt datetime);

insert into t (dt) values ('2022-10-20 12:34:56');

select *, CONVERT(DATE, dt) from t;
```

Result:

```
dt                       (No column name)
-----------------------  ----------
2022-10-20 12:34:56.000  2022-10-20
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/stUcGmBt).

Comment: did not work. keeps turning back time

Comment: It may be your client tool, UI application, or your custom app. What are you using to display the result of the query?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use CAST instead.

```
CAST(name_of_the_field AS DATE)
```

Comment: did not work. keeps turning back time

Comment: I'm curious what your datetime format is. I am wondering if SQL is not able to convert the value to a date because it doesn't see it as one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the only way that have returned the result I want to reach was using

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, TB.COLUM, 103) AS 'NAME'`.

But as mentioned before, this is not a good practice, and than I resolved to made do the convertion in the report tool of the system that am I working